# Finding the particular solution using the general solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Obtain the general solution of the different equation

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-3\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=20\sin x.$$

Hence find the particular solution for which : $y=0$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ when $x=0$.

Comment: To find a particular solution, you would have to consider two simultaneous, one where you put x=0,y=0 and in the other one you first differentiate the general solution and put the first derivative and x=0. I don't see the fuss. Do tell if any other unforeseen complication crops up..

Comment: sorry i just edited the question

Comment: Did you implement what I wrote..

Comment: So my particular solution is: $y =2sinx+6cosx$. is it right

Comment: Yeah! I think you got it..

Comment: Are you sure, "i think" makes me doubt myself.

Comment: from the general solution, we can know directlly the particular solution without the initial conditions

Comment: Ok You answered it right, for the future plug in the derivatives and see for yourself..

Comment: why so harsh when it comes to a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the particular solution, you simply take your general solution and plug in the values that you are given for the particular solution.

Your general solution is

$$y=Ae^x+Be^{2x}+2\sin x+6\cos x.$$

You have given that the particular solution has the properties $y(0)=0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}(0)=0$. The first condition means that when $x=0$, then $y=0$, so plug $x=0$ into your general solution and set it equal to $0$:

$$0 = A+B+6.$$

To use the second condition, you first need to differentiate your general solution:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=Ae^x+2Be^{2x} + 2\cos(x) - 6\sin(x),$$

and then the second condition says that when $x=0$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, so you can plug in $x=0$, and set it equal to $0$:

$$0 = A+2B+2.$$

What you have now is two equations in the two unknowns $A$ and $B$, which you can solve. Take the resulting values for $A$ and $B$ and plug them back into your general solution: You now have the particular solution you were looking for.

Comment: So my particular solution is: $y=2sinx+6cosx$ is it right

Comment: What is the benefit of finding the value of $A$ and $B$

Comment: @JamesM00 that doesn't look right. For instance, your solution does not have the property that $y=0$ whenever $x=0$. We have that $2\sin(0)+6\cos(0) = 6\neq 0$.

Comment: @JamesM00 I get $A=-10$ and $B=4$, so that $y = -10e^x+4e^{2x}+2\sin(x)+6\cos(x)$.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help